# Can i use C# 11 features in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm studying the new features about C# 11 and i don`t know if i can use it with .NET 6.0 or only in .NET 7.0.

I also saw that i can lock the version of C# like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>11</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there a good practice locking the version? Thinking that if there's a new feature in the language it can brake my application.
Or just let it with latest is good enough?

Comment: Perhaps you should use `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>`. Also, remember that this only matters when writing the code and compiling it. At runtime this is in the rearview mirror.

Comment: Set `<LangVersion>` to `preview` (or `11`) and `<TargetFramework>` to `net6.0`. It need not be targeted to `.net7.0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official blog - [Early peek at C# 11 features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/early-peek-at-csharp-11-features/) - states:

> Visual Studio 17.1 (Visual Studio 2022 Update 1) and .NET SDK 6.0.200 include preview features for C# 11! You can update Visual Studio or download the latest .NET SDK to get these features.
>
> (...)
>
> Your .csproj file might look like:
>
> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>     <PropertyGroup>
>         <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
>         <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
>         <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
>         <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
>         <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
>     </PropertyGroup>
> </Project>
> ```

Using the latest version of the language and its preview features for studying is completely fine! (For production code it's nuanced.)

Comment: When you say nuanced, does that mean there be dragons? For example, I'd love to use the required keyword.

Comment: It's nuanced in the sense that a preview feature is not guaranteed to work correctly, but if it makes the code better that using it may actually result in higher quality. Using preview features for PROD really depends on what the application is, the team, risks, etc. Basically, it's a choice, not a default.

Answer (score 2):

C# 11 is supported only on .NET 7 and newer versions.

C# 10 is supported only on .NET 6 and newer versions.

C# 9 is supported only on .NET 5 and newer versions.